# How to Reconvert an interface of values with a wrapper type?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface.

```
interface MyInterface {
    carrot: string;
    apple: { isObj: true };
}
```

and I'd like to transform it with a wrapper type that will match the interface key and value exactly. (e.g. wrap with Promise/Observable/Function)

```
// My attempt..
type WrapWithPromise = Record<keyof MyInterface, Promise<MyInterface[keyof MyInterface]>>

const myObj = {} as WrapWithPromise // Duct Type Test
myObj.apple.then(data => {
    console.log(data) // shows as "string | { isObj: boolean; }"
})
```

The issue with the above code is that each of the keys have a union of the possible value types instead of a direct type mapped. `string | { isObj: boolean }`

How can I get the keys to match the first interface exactly instead of a union type? E.g. `apple` key to be recognized as `{ isObj: boolean; }` **only** instead of a union of

```
string | { isObj: boolean }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map each key to a type based on that key

```
type WrapWithPromise = {
  [K in keyof MyInterface]: Promise<MyInterface[K]>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5BOKKAezAC5kBnMKUAcwG5SLk4ADgIA2EJgWTBmAeQBGAKyZsArigC%20PEmtKkA9LuRh0AlAHUog08DAALAAp0AtlJQBeZACUICWlAAmADwA1hDotDBoWDiwiBAANMgOtM7MEAEY2JAxSADaIWERGdF4EAC6AHzlpEYmyOaW1vZOLsjuxGTIOQDSkiDI%20eGRmbixpUxJKWlFWSXdFaTaJKQ%20IKzIjuhy8q2EavzMdRYCVrYTLfrIACLKCGDIACrGKPcQrKQbWwB0giIQn7YQEAACj8cDAcFa5UIvAoK2YtFEn2EtA4ILBcAAlMgLswbLQAO4HOAHABErHYIA4yAAPoRJDIFExZLQERA4CAuMg1CSFhigA)